# What is function of main button on real device when quiting an app

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have noticed the splash screen does not display when user clicks the middle button on a real device to quit an application but if user selects back button from main menu to quit app and relaunches the splash screen will display.

Question is what function is the middle button performing compared to the back pressed and is there a way to ensure the splash screen is displayed when the middle button is used to quit an application.

Thanks.

Comment: The HOME button (usually in the middle) does not "quit a application". It is more analogous to minimizing a window in a windowed operating system (e.g., Windows, OS X, desktop Linux). With regards to the splash screen, just get rid of it entirely, as splash screens waste the user's time while adding no value to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HOME button takes the user to the home screen (also called the Launcher). The BACK button by default finishes the current activity, which usually results in the user ending up on the previous activity he was in, until he reaches the home screen. The difference is BACK will explicitly `finish` an Activity, whereas HOME will not.

Comment: ok thanks but why is the splash screen not displayed when the app is relaunched after home button is clicked ?

Comment: Because the Activities were not finished, so the task is still alive. Android simply brings that task to the front, right where the user left it.